# How can I add a UILabel after auto shrink label without overlapping the second one

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I'm doing to labels in iPhone view, the first one is auto sized based on the string contents fetched from a remote webservice although I have another `UILabel` right next to it but when the first label text became very long it overlaps the last label, how can I avoid it ...

Comment: What are your UILabel's starting positions?

Comment: Adjust the frames accordingly, e.g., set the label2.frame.origin.x to be greater or equal to label1.frame.origin.x + label1.frame.size.width.

Comment: the point isn't where the first label starts acutually  because any why  i need the second label to start at the x point starts after the first label finished whatever the first  label height which is dynamically adjusted based on it's contents..

Answer (score 1):

**If you created the Labels through interface-builder**

Create two **UILabel IBOutlet properties** as lbl1 and lbl2.
Then connect the IBOutlet's to interface builder.
Then write the below code in **viewDidLoad**

```
[lbl1 setNumberOfLines:0];
lbl1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[lbl1 sizeToFit];
lbl1.text = @"your text here";

lbl2.frame =  CGRectMake(lbl1.frame.origin.x + lbl1.frame.size.width,  lbl1.frame.origin.y + lbl1.frame.size.height, 100, 50)];    
[lbl2 setNumberOfLines:0];   
lbl2.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;   
[lbl2 sizeToFit];
lbl2.text = @"your text here";
```

**Then don't forget to write/execute/call the code again** *lbl2.frame =  CGRectMake(lbl1.frame.origin.x + lbl1.frame.size.width,  lbl1.frame.origin.y + lbl1.frame.size.height, 100, 50)];* **while assigning text to lbl1.**

**If you created the Labels through Code**

The below code worked for me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //Adding first label
    UILabel* lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 50)];
    lbl1.text = @"vbdsbfdshfisdhfidshufidhsufhdsf dhdsfhdksbf hfsdh fksdfidsf sdfhsd fhdsf sdhfh sdifsdkf ksdhfkds fhdsf dsfkdsfkjdhsfkjdhskfjhsdk fdhsf vbdsbfdshfisdhfidshufidhsufhdsf dhdsfhdksbf hfsdh fksdfidsf sdfhsd fhdsf sdhfh sdifsdkf ksdhfkds fhdsf dsfkdsfkjdhsfkjdhskfjhsdk fdhsf";
    [lbl1 setMinimumFontSize:8.0];
    [lbl1 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0]];
    lbl1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [lbl1 sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl1];

    //Adding second label
    UILabel* lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl1.frame.origin.x + lbl1.frame.size.width, lbl1.frame.origin.y + lbl1.frame.size.height, 100, 50)];  
    lbl2.text = @"vbdsbfdshfisdhfidshufidhsufhdsf dhdsfhdksbf hfsdh fksdfidsf sdfhsd fhdsf sdhfh sdifsdkf ksdhfkds fhdsf dsfkdsfkjdhsfkjdhskfjhsdk fdhsf vbdsbfdshfisdhfidshufidhsufhdsf dhdsfhdksbf hfsdh fksdfidsf sdfhsd fhdsf sdhfh sdifsdkf ksdhfkds fhdsf dsfkdsfkjdhsfkjdhskfjhsdk fdhsf";
    [lbl2 setMinimumFontSize:8.0];
    [lbl2 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [lbl2 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0]];
    lbl2.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [lbl2 sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl2];

    [lbl1 release];
    [lbl2 release]; 

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: it's looking cool but the the label is built using interface builder

Comment: ho!! you have wasted my time... you have to mention the details in question.else others will start down voting... :) Any way i have updated my answer.please check it